# Server Error 500 - Edit Tab of Managing Custom Fields of Custom Content Types

Tags: 7, media, files, debugging

Alright, I've got a very irritating error with my site. Whenever I try and Edit a file or image field I get what appears to be a half-loaded page (see image below) [image]

I have check an error log and have received this error at about the same time I was accessing this type of page...

```
 [15-Jun-2016 22:03:35 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory 
    size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9332483 bytes) in 
    /home/cocempro/public_html/portal/includes/database/database.inc on line 2171
```

And while double checking that maybe it wasn't just my browser, I also have received this error from Internet Edge (I don't normally use it, just thought I'd try):

```
SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. GET - http://example.org/admin/structure/types/manage/site-photograph-gallery/fields/field_-images
```

So is this with my server or my Drupal installation? I will clarify that I have found that no other field type (either text, date, summary, whatever) is affected by this, only file and image field types.

Any ideas?

------EDIT----
Oh and none of the other tabs (such as Widget settings, or delete) are affected by this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a max_post_limit issue, requiring I go from 128 to 256 on my PHP version configuration.